# Proportionally, what is more affected by a hot and high takeoff - a electrically driven propeller or a turbofan?

Tags: engine, turbofan, electric-engine, high-altitude

My assumption would be the electrically driven propeller would be less affected compared to turbofans at high altitudes and take off as although the air would be less dense at these ambient conditions, the electric motor itself should be unaffected. In a turbofan my assumption would be that both combustion efficiency in the core and propulsion efficiency by the fan would be negatively affected.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Combustion *efficiency* would not be affected, but the maximum power would as it would only be able to burn less fuel in the less available air.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this assumption correct?

Generally, yes. However, specific combinations of powerplant and propeller might make that difference moot.